# MVC Ajax FormCollection : Parsing collection

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, formcollection

I have a form with a mixture of controles which I pass as FormCollection to my Controller with Ajax:

```
        $.ajax({
            url: this.href,
            type: 'POST',
            data: { collection: $("#CreateNewForm").serialize() },
            dataType: 'json'
        });
```

In my Controller, I can't seem to parse the collection. All values are null.

```
string theme = collection["Themes"]; //This returns null.
```

But if I parse my collection to a list with...

```
        List<object> list = new List<object>();
        for (int i = 0; i < collection.AllKeys.Count(); ++i)
        {
            list.Add(collection.Get(i));
        }
```

...then I get a List with `count = 1` and `list[0] ="Themes=6&Screens=5&Pages=4&Panels=1"` so it seems as if Themes does have a value of 6 but why `string theme = collection["Themes"]` returns `null` is unclear to me.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just `data: $("#CreateNewForm").serialize(),`, but why in the world are you using `FormCollection` instead of binding to your model.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, the controls I mentioned are bound to difference models.

Comment: The use a view model

Comment: For my Index Page I am using a view model : @model Lambada.ViewModels.ExecutionViewModel but seeing that there are other controls on my index page which do not form part the form I want to save to my db, how do I go about passing only specifc controls?

Comment: Then your POST method should be `public ActionResult YouMethod(ExecutionViewModel model) and in will be correctly bound using `data: $("#CreateNewForm").serialize(),` (assuming you generate you form controls correctly)

Comment: I am getting lost now. My ViewModel in turn is a collection on other models.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142172/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-rico-strydom).